SQLAlchemy retrieves only columns from one table in join
I'm trying to join two tables.
User: id, email, nickname
Notes: id, user_id (foreign key), remind_time, message
However, when I try to do the following:
query = select(DBUser.email, DBUser.nickname, DBNote.message)
                    .join(DBNote, (DBUser.id == DBNote.user_id))
                    .where(DBNote.remind_time < current_time)
                    .limit(high).offset(low)
result = (await self._session.execute(query)).scalars().all()

But I get only DBUser.email data.
I'm using asynchronous session.
I tried to retrieve the same data in pgadmin4 in query tool and it worked well.
I tried to rearrage fields, to retrieve all data from both tables, to use select_from.
Franky speaking I cannot understand why such an easy request in sql is so complicated in sqlalchemy.
What am I doing wrong?

Please provide some sample data and minimal model definitions so that we have a [mre] to test against.

try removing .scalars()

Read the docs Scalars.

Removing scalars helped. I misunderstood Row type
